# WebRTC getUserMedia not working for hosted application

Tags: audio, video, websocket, stream, webrtc

I hosted a simple webRTC project(js,css files) in a public server. Although I can access my camera and mic when I hosed the project locally, getUserMedia does not access my camera and microphone when I hosted it in a public server and access via a url.

Is there anyway to access a local stream when the web is remotely accessed via URL?

Comment: the getUserMedia API is only available when https is used (or on localhost)

Comment: Thanks. I think this was the issue.